# MongoDB updateMany set a boolean field using equals

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I have an `IsDefault` field in my model, and I want to set it to `true` for one document only and `false` for the others. Is this possible in a single query? I tried

```
{ $set: { IsDefault: {$eq: [_id, id ]}}}
 
{ $set: { IsDefault: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [$_id, id] }, then: true, else: false } } } }
```

and it didn't work. I also tried passing a lambda expression but it won't build either. Any idea if this is possible or do I need to use two seperate updateOne statements to the the current IsDefault to false, and the new one to true?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with an aggregation pipeline update like this:

```java
db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                IsDefault: {
                    $eq: ["$_id", ObjectId("5f65c2fcaf29d00898173d03")]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

here's a full example using mongodb.entities:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Book : Entity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test", "localhost");

            var books = new[] {
                new Book { Title = "book 1"},
                new Book { Title = "book 2"},
                new Book { Title = "book 3"}
            };

            await books.SaveAsync();

            var stage = new Template<Book>(@"
            {
                $set: {
                    IsDefault: {
                        $eq: ['$_id', ObjectId('<idvalue>')]
                    }
                }
            }")
            .Tag("idvalue", books[1].ID);

            await DB.Update<Book>()
                    .Match(_ => true)
                    .WithPipelineStage(stage)
                    .ExecutePipelineAsync();
        }
    }
}
```